# How to create image using barcode

Tags: c#, .net, itext, barcode, itext7

I would like to create `Image` from `Barcode128` using iText7.

In iText5 it works well like as follows:

```
    var barcode = new Barcode128();
    ...                       
    System.Drawing.Image image = barcode.CreateDrawingImage(Color.Black, Color.White);
```

However there is no such method `CreateDrawingImage` in iText7. How do I achieve the same functionality in iText 7? Could you please advise?

**UPDATE:**

Such functionality has been indeed removed from iText7 and it was a conscious decision. iText7 provides all the means to put a barcode to a PDF document, however generating an image is a different story.

Comment: Such functionality has been indeed removed from iText7. But please could you tell what do you want to do with that System.Drawing.Image ? Perhaphs we could suggest some kind of a workaround. ?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk thanks for the reply. The thing is that I would like to use that Image not only in pdf files, but in other places as well. So it is important to get this barcode as an Image, or some array of bytes.. But I cannot find the way to do this using iText7..

Comment: Also there is `barcode.CreateFormXObject(ColorConstants.BLACK,ColorConstants.WHITE, pdfDocument);`. Maybe it is possible to get bytes from `PdfFormXObject` object?

Comment: @Ronald you won't be able to get image bytes from `PdfFormXObject`. iText7 does not have the functionality in question as Uladzimir mentioned and this was a conscious decision. We provide all the means to put a barcode to a PDF document, generating an image is a different story. I recommend taking a look at ZXing library to achieve your goal.

Comment: @AlexeySubach Thank you for an explanation and tips. It is clear now. But just to know why such functionality was consciously removed in iText7?

Comment: @Ronald users created raster barcode images and added them to documents, which resulted in poor quality. Now you pretty much cannot do that with pure iText as you've noticed and you get nice vector barcodes in your resultant PDFs